# Do we know who Robert's mother is?

Tags: character, taboo

At the beginning of [*Taboo*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3647998/) season 1 James Delaney is visited by an old farmer wanting money for hiding some illegitimate son of Delaney's father for 10 years. But what is an immediate guess then becomes reality when it is clarified later in the show that said lad Robert is actually James Delaney's very own son.

However, what I didn't consider until talking with someone else about this is that he could even be the son of him and his half-sister Zilpha and was hidden for exactly that reason. But I'm not sure this is ever clarified and Zilpha certainly never got involved with Robert during the course of the show.

So, **is it ever hinted who Robert's mother is, specifically whether it is Zilpha?** Can we draw some reasonable conclusions from the story at least, does it even make sense for her to be his mother? Or has it maybe been commented on or analysed from the outside? Or is this matter deliberately left open?